# SIGTSTP in codechef ide

Tags: runtime-error

I've written a code to solve [Buying new tablet](https://www.codechef.com/problems/TABLET) problem from codechef. Although everything goes well in CLION and Visual Studio, even outputs are correct, codechef compiler says runtime error `SIGTSTP`. I'm new to this site, can not understand what it says. I've done a little research on Google, but nothing.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int T,N,B,W,H,P;
    bool isGr = false;
    cin >> T;
    while (T--){
        cin >> N;
        cin >> B;
        vector <int> tablets;
        while (N--){
            cin >> W;
            cin >> H;
            cin >> P;
            if (P <= B) {
                tablets.push_back(W*H);
                isGr = true;
            }
            else isGr = false;
        }
        if (isGr){
            sort(tablets.begin(),tablets.end());
            cout << tablets.back() << endl;
            tablets = {};
        } else cout << "no tablet" << endl;
        isGr = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition
'''else isGr=false;'''
in second while loop, is not required....